# Copying a Pivot Table to another sheet that has another pivot table

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

Im trying to copy a PivotTable from another workbook to another. I was able to copy the PivotTable, but I'm having problem when pasting it.

Here is the screenshot of the error

[image: Error Message]

And here is my code

```
    Dim previous As Workbook
    Dim latest As Workbook

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
    previous.Activate
    
    
    Sheets("PD").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").TableRange2.Copy
    
    latest.Activate
    
    Worksheets("PD").Activate
    Range("U9").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Range("A1").Select
    
    Selection.PasteSpecial
```

Also please do not that the parameters for the pivotable coppied, also exist in the destination page. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit. It seems that the pivot table i was pasting was overlapping to the existing pivot table on the destination page.